# Is there a Linux script that can show all hard drive information?

Tags: hard-disk

I am looking for a Linux script that can be run from the command line, that can show all hard drives' information at the same time, such as name, UUID, mount point, TYPE, free space/available space/total size/use% in MB, etc.

I know the following command:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
lsblk
df -h
lsblk -o NAME,UUID -f
blkid -o list
```

But one script would be much easier. I don't know how to make script.

Comment: So why don't you put them in a script or shell function?

Comment: I don't know how to make script.  I am a very new linux user.

Answer (score -1):

First create a file:

```
touch myscript.sh
```

Next edit the file (use your preferred editor):

```
vi myscript.sh
```

to save the file press `esc` key, type `:wq`, press `enter` key

Add what you want:

```
#!/bin/sh

ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
lsblk
df -h
lsblk -o NAME,UUID -f
blkid -o list
```

Make the file exactable:

```
chmod 775 myscript.sh
```

Run the script:

```
./myscript.sh
[OR]
sh myscript.sh
```

---

To take it one step further, add this line to you `.bashrc` file and `source` it:

```
vi ~/.bashrc

ADD this line at the bottom: 

export PATH=$PATH:/absolute/path/of/directory/my/script/is/in

source ~/.bashrc
```

example:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/lhome/myuserfolder
```

Now you can be anywhere on your system and just type: `myscript.sh` and your script should run.

Comment: You can not say: “type vi, add what you want.” You must include “press a … press `esc` `:wq`”. P.S. my favourite editor is `sed`.

Comment: I agree with @richard, I would avoid vi with a very new linux user.

Comment: @Richard, I edited the post to include the save `:wq`. I agree it is advance but it's just a reliable text editor that is on most *nix boxes that is why I said it. @linuxnorth, glad to help, accept the answer if your question has been answered. Thanks

Comment: `cat` and here-doc (`<<EOF`) is easier.